# serilog.sinks.mssqlservercore causes a FileNotFoundException

Tags: serilog

I'm trying to use Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore (1.1.0) with Serilog.Settings.Configuration (2.2.0).

Serilog.Settings.Configuration works fine with sinks like File and Seq.

As soon as I add Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore to the project.json and tries to run the program again, I get an "Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

If I remove the "Configuration" nuget and add the mssqlcore sink in the code, then it works just fine.

Anybody know how to combine these two nuget??

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade Serilog.Settings.Configuration to 2.3 which is still in development. This is a known issue and bug which loads the wrong file name for Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore.

You can see details in GitHub.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/39